# VBA code to compare CSV text cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns (A&B) filled with CSV texts. Need a code to return the values:
 present in A but not in B - To be returned in column C 
 and Values present in B but not in A - To be returned in column D
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? We're here to help you with issues not do your work for you.

Comment: If you look up the `AGGREGATE` function as `SMALL`, and take advantage of `--ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0))` being `0` when the value exists in column B or `1` when it does not, then you can use `INDEX` to get the list of values without VBA